# PyQt - pyuic4.bat error "The system cannot find the path specified"

Tags: python, qt, batch-file, cmd, pyqt

In order to update any changes made in Qt Designer (`.ui` file), one needs to run the `pyuic4.bat` file. This updates the code in the `.py` file such that it reflects the changes made in Qt Designer.

Normally running these two lines of code, did the job. The first line changes the directory to where my `.ui` and `.py` files exist. The second line runs the `pyuic4.bat` file to update the `.py` file according to the changes made in the `.ui` file.

```
cd C:\Users\blah\Documents\PythonScripts
C:\Users\blah\Anaconda2\Lib\site-packages\PyQt4\pyuic4 guitemplate.ui >> guicode.py
```

But suddenly, I am getting this error today: `The system cannot find the path specified`. I have also tried running `cmd` as administrator. I am using Anaconda if that helps. What could be the problem?

This is the code that is contained within the `pyuic4.bat` file

```
@"C:\aroot\stage\python" "C:\aroot\stage\Lib\site-packages\PyQt4\uic\pyuic.py" %1 %2 %3 %4 %5 %6 %7 %8 %9
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its impossible for us to know where guitemplate.ui is supposed to be located. If it's along side the bat file then use:

```bat
CD/D "%UserProfile%\Anaconda2\Lib\site-packages\PyQt4"
pyuic4.bat -x guitemplate.ui -o "%UserProfile%\Documents\PythonScripts\guicode.py"
```

If it's along side the intended output file then use:

```bat
CD/D "%UserProfile%\Documents\PythonScripts"
"%UserProfile%\Anaconda2\Lib\site-packages\PyQt4\pyuic4.bat" -x guitemplate.ui -o guicode.py
```

If the above doesn't work then you probably need to change the content of pyuic4.bat to match a possible changed path to your python folder, *for example:*

```bat
@"C:\Anaconda2\python" "C:\Anaconda2\Lib\site-packages\PyQt4\uic\pyuic.py" %1 %2 %3 %4 %5 %6 %7 %8 %9
```

Comment: Hi, the solutions did not work... I am still getting the same error. It was working fine for months but then it wasn't working one day. I also tried putting all the files in a single folder.

Comment: I have updated my answer, the most likely fix is to perform the change I have indicated in your `pyuic4.bat` file, but I have also now included the `-x` and `-o` options to the other two commands just in case.